# read() and buffer size errors in (C Linux)

Tags: c, linux, file, buffer

//EDIT: I set the first handle's flag as O_WRONLY, it should be O_RDONLY and that was causing a problem.

I'm working on a simple program in Linux using C that would copy text from one file to another.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

...

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int cp_from = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY);
    int cp_to = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0777);    //make a descriptor for each file
    int size = lseek(cp_from,0,SEEK_END);               //check the size of the first file
    lseek(cp_from,0,SEEK_SET)                           //return to the start of the file, don't know if that's needed
    char *buf = (char*) malloc (size*sizeof(char));     //allocate enough memory to fit all text from 1st file into char array
    read(cp_from,buf,sizeof(buf)-1);                    //read from the 1st file to the char array
    printf("%s",buf);                                   //print the buf
    close(cp_from);
    close(cp_to);
...
```

So, later I would write() the "buf" to "cp_to" and that would (hopefully) work. But, here's only half of the work because it stopped working at this point, "buf" is empty and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` is `char*` size.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: That's my first question on StackOverflom, i'm not used to formatting here yet ^^.
I changed the "sizeof(buf)-1" to "size", still doesn't work.

Comment: `lseek()` returns `off_t` not `int`.

Comment: "still doesn't work" is not useful.  Explain the results and what your expectations were.

Comment: the posted code is missing the two statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/stat.h>`

Comment: when calling `open()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 in the standard,  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect on the parameter passed to `malloc()` and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: when calling `read()`, 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the `read()` function does not NUL terminate the input buffer and there is no assurance that the input buffer does not already contain 1 or more NUL bytes.  So this line: `printf("%s",buf);` will not work.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stdout, "buf, size );`

Comment: this line: `lseek(cp_from,0,SEEK_SET) ` is missing a trailing semicolon ';'

Comment: the prototype for `malloc()` is in stdlib.h, so the posted code is missing: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: never access any parameter from main() beyond `arg[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure that command line parameter was actually entered.

Comment: the descriptor: cp_to is set but never used, Overall, the posted code does not perform the desired operation. suggest replacing: printf( "%s"buf); with `write(cp_to, const buf, size);`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some review points:

1. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. Don't use `sizeof` on a heap pointer thinking it will return anything to do with the allocated buffer's size; it won't. You'll get the size of the pointer.
3. Use proper types, not just `int` for everything. Types matter, and not all types are like `int`.
4. Don't treat random data read from a file as a string.
5. Don't do I/O and not check return values. I/O can fail.
6. ... so can memory allocations.

It's probably better to use a small (or smallish) fixed-size buffer, and read/write in a loop. That way your program uses a bounded amount of memory, regardless of the size of the file.

Comment: thanks for the tips. Yeah, i thought about using fixed size buffers but i just wanted to see how all those functions would work together (i kinda new to C programming in Linux).
I changed the "sizeof(buf)-1" to "size-1" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can also add "Always use proper types".  For example, `lseek` returns `off_t`, not `int`, per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. still has a warning about unused variable `argc` (see comments)
2. is missing code to check for error indications returned from system function calls
3. actually works

and now the code

```
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    int cp_from = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    int cp_to = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0777);

       //make a descriptor for each file


    size_t size = (size_t)lseek(cp_from,0,SEEK_END);               //check the size of the first file
    lseek(cp_from,0,SEEK_SET);
    //return to the start of the file, don't know if that's needed

    char *buf = malloc (size);     //allocate enough memory to fit all text from 1st file into char array
    read( cp_from, buf, size );                    //read from the 1st file to the char array
    write( cp_to, buf, size );                                   //print the buf
    close(cp_from);
    close(cp_to);
}
```

Comment: oh, returning the file pointer to the start of the file is absolutely needed, otherwise the `read()` function would only return a 0, indicating EOF